# AWS certificate timestamp format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I want to check the expiration date of an SSL certificate placed in the Certificate Manager on my AWS account. When retrieving a certificate from AWS using the CLI - like this:

```
aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn *arn*
```

I get values looking like '1478433600.0' returned in the "NotAfter" property. I cannot recognize the format and I can't find anything in the docs - can anybody shed some light on this one for me?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/describe-certificate.html

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is

> unix epoch time

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

The timestamp you pasted represents this date and time:

Sunday, November 6, 2016 12:00:00 PM

See for yourself: https://www.epochconverter.com/